# Kill tftp command that's running in subshell

Tags: linux, shell, tftp

I'm running the following command in Linux:

`sudo ./tftpCommand &`

where my executable tftpCommand file simply gets/puts a data file which sometimes does not exist.
I want to be able to stop the tftp command that was spawned in the subshell before it automatically times out.

Using something like `kill $(jobs -p)` shows that the subshell has been terminated but the tftp still runs -- I know this because several seconds later it prints to the shell that it can't find the file to transfer.

QUESTION: How do I ensure that the tftp command is killed alongside the subshell that runs it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem:

use `pkill -c tftp` to kill any current tftp commands.

I figured this out by using `ps x -o "%p %r %c"`

You can use a similar technique for any of the command names in the COMMAND column (corresponding to the %c and -c ) to kill other processes.

Hope that helps anyone else who stumbles upon the same problem!